# C# - how is this called?

Tags: c#, properties

I have in my code:

```
private string _Username;

public string Username { // How is this called?
    get { return _Username; }
    set { _Username = value; }
}
```

I'm interested in the name of Username. How is it called? Is it "getter and setter" or property or something else?

Comment: it is called Username property of class _Username

Comment: @LostMohican: "_Username" isn't the class, it is the private backing field of the property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public string Username // property name is "Username"
{
  get { return _Username; }  // getter section
  set { _Username = value; } // setter  section
}
```

`Username` is a property which has both getter and setter.

The private member `_Username` is responsible to get or set `Username`.

If you don't use Username anywhere it'll never called, however getter/setting section is called as below:

Getter section is called when you write like code as below:

```
string anotherStringVariable = Username; // getter section is called
//OR
CallAFunctionToPassValue(Username); // getter section is called
```

Setter section is called when you write like code as below:

```
Username = otherStringVariable; // setting section is called
```

Comment: Hello @Fischermaen, you're right!
Seems the question is from the beginner and that is why I explained accordingly, thank for your time.

Answer (score 10):

```
 private string _Username; // This is a "private field", the "backing field" for property Username

 public string Username // This is a "public property"
 {
     get { return _Username; }  // This is called the "getter"
     set { _Username = value; } // This is called the "setter"
 }
```

Comment: Worth noting that `_Username` is the backing field for `Username`. Also, you can have auto-implemented properties: `public string Username { get; set; }`

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: You're totally right, I've added it to the sample.

Answer (score 5):

`Username` is a property here.

Answer (score 5):

Property.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

- property `Username` with getter and setter methods defined
- field `_Username` (private)

Answer (score 1):

Username is a Property. A Property is essentially Get and Set methods in disguise. The compiler will generate a method for each of the get and set blocks.